# swagger-codegen - How do I supply a body to the generated C# SDK method?

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm using the (unofficial) swagger-codegen-cli Docker container from https://hub.docker.com/r/jimschubert/swagger-codegen-cli/ which pulls swagger-codegen from the master branch before it runs. I tried grabbing the recently documented (official) swagger-codegen-cli from https://hub.docker.com/r/swaggerapi/swagger-codegen-cli/, but it appears to be unavailable at the moment.

As it stands with the unofficial cli, I have generated a C# SDK from swagger documentation that contains the following:

```
/api/customer/{zoneId}/files/cover/gallery: {
    get: {
        tags: [
            "FileUpload"
        ],
        summary: "Get all files in customer cover gallery",
        operationId: "FileUpload_GetCustomerCoverFiles",
        consumes: [ ],
        produces: [
            "application/json",
            "text/json"
        ],
        parameters: [
            {
                name: "zoneId",
                in: "path",
                description: "",
                required: true,
                type: "integer",
                format: "int32"
            }
        ],
        responses: {
            200: {
                description: "OK",
                schema: {
                    type: "array",
                    items: {
                        $ref: "#/definitions/FileUploadGalleryItemModel"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    post: {
        tags: [
            "FileUpload"
        ],
        summary: "Upload file to customer cover gallery",
        operationId: "FileUpload_CreateCustomerCoverGalleryItem",
        consumes: [
            "application/octet-stream"
        ],
        produces: [
            "application/json",
            "text/json"
        ],
        parameters: [
            {
                name: "zoneId",
                in: "path",
                description: "",
                required: true,
                type: "integer",
                format: "int32"
            },
            {
                name: "payload",
                in: "body",
                description: "",
                required: true,
                type: "byte[]",
                format: "binary"
            }
        ],
        responses: {
            200: {
                description: "OK",
                schema: {
                    type: "array",
                    items: {
                        $ref: "#/definitions/FileUploadGalleryItemModel"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

The 'payload' is provided within the body of the request, however I don't see any way to provide the body to the method generated within the SDK with the following signature: `public List<FileUploadGalleryItemModel> FileUploadCreateCustomerCoverGalleryItem (int? zoneId)`.

Any suggestions on what I might be overlooking or doing incorrectly?

Comment: For `payload`, have you tried documented it as `file` instead? e.g. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml#L269-L273

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Keep up the great work!

Comment: Np :) please accept my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can document `payload` as file (form parameter) instead, e.g. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/test/resources/2_0/petstore.yaml#L269-L273, and you will find sample code in the auto-generated documentation (please take a look at the auto-generated README.md as a starting point)